# Is $\cos(x^2)$ the same as $\cos^2(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I want to know something about trigonometrical functions, is $\cos(x^2)$ the same as $\cos^2(x)$ ?

Comment: $\cos^2(x) = \cos(x)\times \cos(x)$ and $\cos(x^2) = \cos(x \times x)$ So no. But beware, the notation $\cos^{-1}(x)$ is ambiguous. It can denote the inverse cosine function or the reciprocal of the cosine function.

Comment: When you have a doubt like this and you are lazy to find a formal proof that concludes that your hyphotesis is true, you can probe a few random values until you find a counterexample that invalidate the hyphotesis of your question. For example, is $cos (33^2) = cos^2(33)$? No? Then you can properly conclude that the answer of your question is false :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general function $f$, which can be about anything and is $\cos$ in your case and with $g(x)=x^n$,
$$f^n(x) := (f(x))^n = g\circ f(x) = g(f(x))$$
and
$$f(x^n) := f(\underbrace{x\cdot x \cdot \ldots}_{n \text{ times}}) = f \circ g(x) = f(g(x))$$
are two different functions.
Note for trigonometric functions, $\cos^{-1}$ sometimes refers to $\arccos$, and sometimes to $\sec = \frac1{\cos}$, so you should be careful about exponentiating functions.

Answer (score 4):

One of the first things you may observe is that $(\cos {\small{(}}x{\small{)}})^2\geqslant0$ whereas $\cos(x^2)$ may be equal to a negative number. (Why?)

In blue, a graph of the function $\color{blue}{\cos^2(x)}$ and in red a graph of the function $\color{red}{\cos(x^2)}$.

[image: made using GeoGebra]

Some say, a good ***plot*** is worth a million words! :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are few functions such that $f^2(x)=f(x^2)$: essentially the powers of $x$, $f(x)=x^n$: $f^2(x)=(x^n)^2=(x^2)^n=f(x^2)$.

The rule is more often $f^2(x)\ne f(x^2)$. Just an example with$f(x)=x+1$: $(x+1)^2\ne x^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

No $\cos^2(x)$ means $(\cos x)^2$. This is not the same as $\cos(x^2)$.

Comment: Why $(cos x)^{2}$ is not the same as $cos(x^2)$?

Comment: Just plug in a value, e.g. $x=\pi/2$ (that is 90 degrees), then $(\cos(x))^2=0^2=0$, but $\cos(\pi^2/4)<0$ because $\pi/2<\pi^2/4<\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

No. $\cos x^2=\cos(x^2)=\cos(x\times x)$ while $\cos^2(x)=\cos(x)\times \cos(x)=(\cos(x))^2$.

Comment: why is my answer downvoted but yvesdaoust answer isn't?

Comment: Yves's answer isn't repeating what was said a year ago, but adding additional useful information.