# Inverse of $\tan^{2}\theta$?

Tags: trigonometry

I re-arranged: $$3\tan^{2} x -1=0$$ to get $\tan^{2}\theta = \frac{1}3$. I noticed the inverse of the $cos, sin$ and $tan$ functions are written as $\cos^{-1}\theta,  \sin^{-1}\theta$ and $\tan^{-1}\theta$ respectively, does this mean the inverse of $\tan^{2}\theta$ would equal $\tan^{(2-1=1)}\theta = \tan\theta$ ? Also is it referred to Arc-$function$ or the inverse of the function, I've heard they're two different things but the distinction is ambiguous to me.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help to address some notation issues, particularly those involving trig functions: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728476/is-sin2x-the-same-as-sin-x2/728591#728591

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, this is not correct. Perhaps the notation is misleading, but

$$\cos^{-1} \theta \neq \frac{1}{\cos \theta}.$$

That is why I prefer to use the arc notation as in $\arccos \theta$.

The notations $\cos^{-1} \theta$ and $\arccos \theta$ represent the same thing, which is, roughly speaking, the inverse of $\cos \theta$ (although it is not a true inverse since $\cos$ is not injective).

Back to your question:

We can simplify $3\tan^{2} \theta -1=0$ to get $|\tan \theta|= \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$. You may then use the fact that $\tan \theta$ is odd and that it is $\pi$-periodic to find all of the solutions.

Comment: is $arccos\theta = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$ ?

Comment: @James Unfortunately not. It really is just a matter of bad notation.

Comment: So... 1, Is arccos the same as $\cos^{-1}$ . 2, how is the inverse of a function squared found? Square root and then inverse?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. To find the inverse is a bit tricky. Take the square root and account for the fact that same values of $\tan$ are negative.

Comment: Not so much "bad" notation, as the unfortunate confluence of notation from two different usages in mathematics (somewhat like the over-use of the word "normal").

Comment: does $cos\theta^{-1} $ not equal $\frac{1}{cos\theta}$

Comment: @Tobi That is quite ambiguous notation. It could mean $\arccos \theta$, $\cos \frac{1}{\theta}$, or $\frac{1}{\cos \theta}$.

Comment: When I posted the question I asked if arccos$\theta$ was equivalent to $\frac{1}{cos\theta}$ and I was told no, but then I asked if arccos was equal to $cos^{-1}$ and was told yes, so its quite confusing...

Answer (score 1):

REMEMBER: $tan^2\;x$ is a simplification of $(tan(x))^2$.

It's easier than it seems, root both sides so $tan(x) = \frac{\pm 1}{\sqrt3}$

Now inverse tan $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} $ ...  $tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$

and you get: $\theta = 30$ this is the principal value (closest to the origin); you can find the limitless other solutions by $\pm 180$

Comment: Nitpick: when you take square root of both sides, it should be $\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.